# Mvc use string on multiple page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a patient web app. When user add new patient, I want to keep this patient information(name, surname, phone etc.) I created a static class for patient info values. I set datas on this class. How can I get this info on another views?
This is info class: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd8R0.jpg

I tried access on view like that: 
@{Dentilog.Models.patientinfo.patient_id}

I getting data on views like that (I already set data values on form input)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RQgC.jpg

and in controller: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH0Ox.jpg

I dont have any problem for getting data. How can use that data on another page?

Comment: Please paste your code as *text*, not as an image.

Comment: Ever heard of cache? or why not store it in some temporary location and retrieve it(yeah, we're back to cache)?

Comment: You can create a view model, which is just a model, then put these properties and pass it as model when returning to your view.

Comment: Note: static means *there will never be more than one of these, ever*. Is your web application ever used by more than one person? If the answer is yes, stop immediately. And even if the answer is no, it’s still not a good idea. You have Session for storing data in a session, for example.

Comment: you can put it in session object and then can access like @(cast)session["keyname"].id on any view